# How to log some messages to a log file and some messages to stdout using logging in Python

Tags: python, logging

I have the below code base for logging:

```
import logging

logFormatter = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s [%(threadName)-12.12s] [%(levelname)-5.5s]  %(message)s")
rootLogger = logging.getLogger()
rootLogger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
fileLogger = logging.getLogger()
fileLogger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

fileHandler = logging.FileHandler("new_log.log")
fileHandler.setFormatter(logFormatter)
fileLogger.addHandler(fileHandler)

consoleHandler = logging.StreamHandler()
consoleHandler.setFormatter(logFormatter)
rootLogger.addHandler(consoleHandler)

fileLogger.debug('debug message')
rootLogger.debug('debug message')
fileLogger.info('info message')
fileLogger.warn('warn message')
rootLogger.warn('warn message')
fileLogger.error('error message')
fileLogger.critical('critical message')
rootLogger.critical('critical message')
```

My main purpose is to use the rooLogger to log to the console and the fileLogger to log to a file . How can i achieve that here ?

I am not sure if the above way is correct or not.

Can someone please throw some light ?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logger-objects